# delete systemd not-found services

Tags: linux, debian, unix, systemd

My server shows multiple missing services. How can i delete them from Systemd? They are not-found.

**systemctl -a** shows: multiple not found
**systemctl reset-failed** shows: still shows

These (none of them are in /etc/systemd/ or /lib/systemd):

exim4.service - i use postfix, i never installed
apache2.service - i use nginx

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, I see that I have a `not-found` mysql service. I can find no files named `mysql` in `/etc/systemd` or `/lib/systemd`, nor do I find any mentions of "mysql" if I grep those directories. It's not at all clear why `systemd` has a reference to this service that it can't find.

Comment: exactly! true! ...

Comment: What distro are you using? If Debian/Ubuntu, then those might be sysv services.

Comment: debian  / systemd

Comment: I have this on Debian 12 after purging "slapd" package via apt. systemd still shows slapd.service, even after I ran `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

systemd tries to load all services which are mentioned in `Wants=`, `Requires=`, `After=`, `Before=`, `RequiresMountsFor=`, `Conflicts=`, `Requisite=`, `PartOf=`, …, `x-systemd.requires=`, `x-systemd.requires-mounts-for=`, `systemd.unit=`, `SYSTEMD_WANTS=`, and also symlinked in `.wants` and `.requires` and probably some other places I forgot.

The units you're seeing must be mentioned somewhere. Systemd doesn't know anything about apache2 or exim4 by itself. Note that systemd will generate "wrapper" services for sysvinit scripts.

Having those services listed in `systemctl --all` output is harmless. There's no need to "delete" them.

Comment: In my case, I eventually found a `mysql` reference in `/etc/init.d/postfix` on this line: `# Should-Start:      postgresql mysql clamav-daemon postgrey spamassassin saslauthd dovecot`. I presume that must be where `systemd` is picking up the reference to it.

Comment: "The units you're seeing must be mentioned somewhere.". I don't think that's true. I installed my own service+timer then stopped, disabled, and deleted the files I put in /etc/systemd/ and `list-units --type service` still lists the service even after `daemon-reload`. They go away with a reboot. It's harmless but annoying.